# Update everything except a few rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a pretty standard table  and I am looking to upgrade all salaries in my  table apart from the 2 highest.

here is what I am  doing:

```
update employee
set salary= salary*1.5
where id not in (select * from employee order by salary desc limit 2)
```

However, I cannot get this right, although it seems straight forward

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are actually using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks

Comment: `select * from ...` returns all the columns of the table, but you check if `id` is in this set, which is obviously not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `salary` is never `NULL`, you can tweak your query to select the salary in the subquery:

```
update employee
    set salary = salary*1.5
     where id not in (select e2.salary from employee e2 order by e2.salary desc limit 2)
```

Comment: typo: shouldn't it be `select e2.id`, not `e2.salary`

Comment: @JGH it did work. but why did it work when all I have is basically just give a an alias to the table?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff . I have the following `update employee e
set salary = salary*1.5
where id not in ( select e.id from employee e2 order by e.salary desc limit 2)` and it works why?  All I have done is giving an alias to the table

Comment: @Camue. . . The query in your comment is incorrect, it should be `e2.id` in the subquery.  The difference is the `*` versus selecting a column.